# Hacer click en una ID variable

Tags: vba

Buenas tardes,

Estoy haciendo una pequeña macro a modo de bot, para introducir datos en una página web que tengo que usar de manera reiterada.

En el código tan solo me falta la última parte, pero no puedo usar getElementByID, ya que la ID es variable, se me habían ocurrido un par de cosillas para salir del paso, pero nada que fuera bueno para un código (los bucles no son nuestros amigos).

A continuación os dejo el código que tengo escrito hasta ahora, y el código de la página, señalando la ID que necesito coger:

> Sub DeclararVenta()
>
> ```
> Dim ie As InternetExplorer
> Dim pagina As HTMLDocument
> Dim buscar As HTMLButtonElement
> Dim chasis As String
> Dim precio As Object
>
> 'Crea el explorador de internet
> Set ie = New InternetExplorer
>
> 'Hacemos visible el explorador
> ie.Visible = True
>
> 'Navega a la página de Cronos
> ie.navigate "https://es-cronos.peugeot.com/dvnWeb/initVehicleArrival.action"
>
> 'Espera a que la página cargue
> Do
> DoEvents
> Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
>
> 'La página cargada la asignamos a la variable "pagina"
> Set pagina = ie.document
>
> ' Recogemos los chasis para la declaración de llegada al concesionario
> chasis = ""
>
> For i = 2 To Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
>
>     chasis = chasis & Range("B" + CStr(i)).Value & ","
>
> Next i
>
> ' Escribimos los chasis
> pagina.getElementById("vehicleList").Value = chasis
> ' Escribimos la fecha
> pagina.getElementById("arrivalDateId").Value = Range("C1").Value
> ' Siguiente página
> pagina.getElementById("addNewArrivalLink").Click
>
> ' Esperamos
> Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:08"))
>
> ' Checkeamos los vehículos
> pagina.getElementById("cb_itemsTable").Checked = True
> ```

Vale, ahora lo que necesito es darle un botón, el cual tiene ID variable, os dejo el código:

```html
<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" id="anchor_1380069774" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="font-size: 11px;" onclick="actionReportLaunched = true; startActionReportPoller();$('#openWaitActionReportDialogTrigger').trigger('click');hideActionReportCloseSpan();$('#waitActionReportTrigger').trigger('click');">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-check">
</span><span class="ui-button-text">
        Declarar llegada de vehículos
```

Como veis el ID es "anchor_XXXXXXXXXX" el número siempre es variable, y no se como llegar a la propiedad ID, para acabar haciendo accediendo a "Click".

Gracias y saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método outerHTML para extraer la información de la etiqueta como un String y luego buscar alguna parte en el texto que te ayude a identificar el botón.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido.. mira por favor [recorrido] y [tour]. tu respuesta fue marcada como de baja calidad. se pide que por favor seas mas explicativo en la respuesta. capaz quien pregunto ni sabe como usar ese metodo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba un selector css para seleccionar el elemento.

[selector css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

```
a[id^=anchor_]
```

[image: selector]

`"^"` en CSS = el atributo comienza con `"anchor_"`

```
pagina.querySelector("a[id^=anchor_]").Click
```